# Enterprise Lib 5.0 not working on Production (Windows Server 2008R2)

Tags: deployment, enterprise, enterprise-library-5

I am using EntLib 5.0-April 2010 Logging on my local machine (for rolling flat file, event log) and everything works fine, when I try to put in production on our web server, it does not work.

Development machine is Windows 7 using VS2010. Production server is Windows Server 2008 R2 with Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 (with network account - not admin)

I am including the LAB DLLs in the project (Common, Logging, ServiceLocation), not in the GAC.

Any ideas?
I read some article and they thought problem caused by permission on Production, is it right?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Start the Registry Editor tool Regedit.exe.
2. Using the Application Event log, expand the outline list in the left panel to locate the following registry subkey: 
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application`
3. Right-click the Application subkey, point to New, and then click Key.
4. Type a new event source name for the key name and press Enter.